# Problem with If statements

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am building a media scrobbler. What I want the program to do is to detect the media from iTunes/MPlayer and have the program send an update via API. I got that part down, but when the same Media Title and Segment (track/episode) is compared to this If statement, it does the same action over again, which I don't want the program to do.

Here is the problematic code that I'm going through:

```
    if ([[segment stringValue] length] == 0 || [[mediatitle stringValue]length] == 0 ) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    else if ([mediatitle stringValue] == ScrobbledMediaTitle && [segment stringValue] == ScrobbledMediaSegment && scrobblesuccess == 1) {
        // Do Nothing
        }
    else {
        int httperror = [self scrobble];
        switch (httperror) {
            case 200:
                [scrobblestatus setObjectValue:@"Scrobble Successful..."];
                [GrowlApplicationBridge notifyWithTitle:@"Scrobble Successful"
                                            description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [mediatitle stringValue], [segment stringValue]] 
                                       notificationName:@"Message"
                                               iconData:nil
                                               priority:0
                                               isSticky:NO
                                           clickContext:[NSDate date]];
                ScrobbledMediaTitle = [mediatitle stringValue];
                ScrobbledMediaSegment = [segment stringValue];
                scrobblesuccess = YES;
                //Set up Delegate
                Melative_ExampleAppDelegate* appDelegate=[NSApp delegate];
                //Set last successful scrobble to statusItem Tooltip
                [appDelegate setStatusToolTip:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MelScrobbleX - Last Scrobble: %@ - %@", [mediatitle stringValue], [segment stringValue]]];               
                NSLog(@"ScrobbledMediaTitle = %@", ScrobbledMediaTitle);
                NSLog(@"ScrobbledMediaSegment = %@" , ScrobbledMediaSegment);
                NSLog(@"BOOL = %d", (int)scrobblesuccess);              
                break;
            case 401:
                // Set Status
                [scrobblestatus setObjectValue:@"Unable to Scrobble..."];
                [GrowlApplicationBridge notifyWithTitle:@"Scrobble Unsuccessful"
                                            description:@"Check your login information and try scrobbling again." 
                                       notificationName:@"Message"
                                               iconData:nil
                                               priority:0
                                               isSticky:NO
                                           clickContext:[NSDate date]];
                scrobblesuccess = NO;
                break;
            default:
                // Set Status
                [scrobblestatus setObjectValue:@"Unable to Scrobble..."];
                [GrowlApplicationBridge notifyWithTitle:@"Scrobble Unsuccessful"
                                            description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unknown Error. Error %i", httperror]
                                       notificationName:@"Message"
                                               iconData:nil
                                               priority:0
                                               isSticky:NO
                                           clickContext:[NSDate date]];
                scrobblesuccess = NO;
                break;              
        }

}
}
```

I try figuring out with the NSLog output and this is what I get:

```
    2010-08-01 21:58:56.935 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaTitle = (null)
2010-08-01 21:58:56.935 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaSegment = (null)
2010-08-01 21:58:56.935 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] BOOL = 0
2010-08-01 21:58:56.935 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] mediatitle = Lia COLLECTION ALBUM "SPECTRUM RAYS"
2010-08-01 21:58:56.936 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] mediasegment = Tori no Uta -StripE REMIX-
2010-08-01 21:58:56.936 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] Scrobbled
2010-08-01 21:58:56.936 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaTitle = Lia COLLECTION ALBUM "SPECTRUM RAYS"
2010-08-01 21:58:56.936 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaSegment = Tori no Uta -StripE REMIX-
2010-08-01 21:58:56.936 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] BOOL = 1
2010-08-01 21:59:06.709 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaTitle = Lia COLLECTION ALBUM "SPECTRUM RAYS"
2010-08-01 21:59:06.709 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaSegment = Tori no Uta -StripE REMIX-
2010-08-01 21:59:06.710 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] BOOL = 1
2010-08-01 21:59:06.710 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] mediatitle = Lia COLLECTION ALBUM "SPECTRUM RAYS"
2010-08-01 21:59:06.710 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] mediasegment = Tori no Uta -StripE REMIX-
2010-08-01 21:59:06.711 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] Scrobbled
2010-08-01 21:59:06.711 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaTitle = Lia COLLECTION ALBUM "SPECTRUM RAYS"
2010-08-01 21:59:06.711 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] ScrobbledMediaSegment = Tori no Uta -StripE REMIX-
2010-08-01 21:59:06.711 MelScrobbleX[7775:a0f] BOOL = 1
```

Can't figure out the reason why the IF statement wouldn't fire since the values are the same and scrobbleSuccess is true.

Comment: I just editted your post. Next time, please, format the code

Comment: Sorry about that... It didn't paste properly... >_<

Comment: It's always a good idea to group the clauses in the if statement even though precedence may be correct.....have you tried that?

Comment: I would suggest you split up your mega function into several smaller functions, that makes the code easier to read.

Comment: I managed to reduce the code. The Scrobble API action is now in a separate function and reports the HTTP code in the integer... Still need to see if that did anything to the IF statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing objects with `==` compares pointer equality. If you want to see whether the objects have the same value (even if they exist in separate memory locations), use `isEqual:` or, in the case of NSString, `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: That fixed the issue... I assumed that == worked with strings since it worked with integers and Boolean values (also because I came from Visual Basic), but I was wrong. I need to break those bad habits. :p